# How do I call a PostgreSQL Function that returns VOID from PGAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, npgsql, pgadmin

I have a simple function defined in Postgresql defines as follows

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Foo(someid_param integer)
RETURNS void AS 
$$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM SomeTable WHERE id = someid_param;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I've tried using EXEC, SELECT and PERFORM

```
PERFORM Foo(100);
```

But I get errors.
What is the correct method for calling this function?

I'm using PGAdmin as my development environment.

Comment: "But I get errors." can you add the error you are getting? Would help

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PERFORM"
LINE 1: PERFORM Foo(122)

Answer (score 3):

`PERFORM` belongs to PL/pgSQL, and `EXEC` isn't valid SQL. So, you can't use them. You should use

```
SELECT foo(100);
```

This should return a single line with an empty column named `foo`.